# Why are engineering departments so large in U.S. universities?

Tags: phd, mathematics, physics, engineering

For a math or physics department at a good university in the United States, there might be 20 or so full-time faculty members, while in the engineering department, I've noticed that there can be more than 100 faculty members -- even over 200 -- and many laboratories.

Why are engineering departments so large, in comparison to, say, math or physics departments?

Is there more funding for engineering research?  If so, does most of this funding come from the government?

I'm thinking of schools with math, physics, and engineering programs that are typically ranked Top 50 or higher (more like Top 30 or higher).

Comment: Can you give any examples of engineering departments with over 200 faculty? That figure sounds far fetched to me. And you do know that there are many types of engineering, right? The label “engineering” is usually applied to multiple departments inside a university, and tyically those departments are grouped in a higher-level organizational structure with a name such as “college of engineering”.

Comment: Also your claim about math departments is outright false. There are very few good US math departments with 20 or so full time faculty members, most of them will have 40-80. So the likely answer is that the premise of your question is incorrect and there isn’t any “why” to explain. But I don’t have enough data to feel comfortable posting this as an answer.

Comment: Who exactly do you count as 'full-time faculty members'? Professors definitely, postdocs?, technical staff at labs? (doesn't exist in math), phd students?

Comment: @DanRomik   CUNY  https://www.ccny.cuny.edu/people  lists 289 faculty and staff at the Grove School of Engineering. UCLA https://samueli.ucla.edu/facts-and-figures/  has 967 PhD candidates in engineering. Makes me expect round about 200 faculty capable of supervising PhDs.

Comment: @puppetsock those are _schools_ of engineering, not departments. According to the page you linked, the UCLA engineering school is comprised of seven academic departments. As I said, there is nothing to explain here other than that OP is comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @DanRomik Are the differences between what engineering schools call "departments" greater than the differences between what math departments call "subfields"?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I don’t know. Not sure such a question can be given a meaningful answer.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: I would say yes, in the sense that in a math department we expect that most of the faculty, regardless of their subfield, can teach most of the core courses of the undergraduate math major; whereas I don't think an electrical engineering professor would be expected to be competent to teach most of the courses in an undergraduate civil engineering program.

Comment: On an administrative level, at least in the US system, if you get a degree from a math department it's typically a degree in "Mathematics", with no subfield specified.  Whereas an engineering degree always specifies which type of engineering.  And the kinds of jobs a degree is expected to qualify you for reflect that as well.

Answer (score 5):

Engineering, like business, is an extremely popular major because it has good employment prospects. It's also well-funded relative to more academic disciplines, because it's easier to get funding from both private and public sources for "useful" research.